# How to change the category collection before load?

Tags: magento2, collection, custom, product-collection

I'm trying to figure out how to change the category collection before load.

To be more specific, I've created a category **'Sales'**. The category is empty with no products. I want to automatically add to this category all the products with discounts.

So i have tried to change the `getProductCollection()` function from `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer` and add a logic check.

The check is simple, if the current category id matches the id of the 'Sales' category, create a new collection and return it otherwise return the default but I can't make it work. The collection's `getSelect()` seems to be right and when I execute the query to my database I get the products I want.

In the class, though the collection keeps coming back with no products.
My collection is being instantiated from this class `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection` because I saw the default collection is of the same type.

Thank you in advance.